# How do I mock one method of an interface?

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to mock the `validate` method of an interface, and have all the other interface methods stubbed return null (I don't really care what happens to them), but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this easily.

Here's what I have:

```
    $validator = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface')
        ->setMethods(array('validate'))
        ->getMock();

    $validator
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('validate')
        ->willReturn(array());

    $validator->validate();
```

Running this gives me a fatal error:

> Class Mock_ValidatorInterface_56c4c003 contains 6 abstract methods and
>   must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

So - I need to somehow tell PHPUnit to stub the other methods that the interface requires. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare all the interface's methods in `->setMethods()`.

Generally, you mock a class and only declare certain methods in `->setMethods()`. The un-mocked methods fall back to the implementations on the original class being mocked.

But if you are mocking an interface, all methods must be implemented by the mock.

Comment: This requires updating all test cases that use this technique for interface X whenever interface X gains another method. Having to explicitly list all methods is bad bad bad.